# Resolving GCP permissions issues

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

So I'm working through the following tutorial: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/machine-learning/solutions/energy_price_forecasting

I've gone through the following code in my terminal and have initialized google cloud. Furthermore, I'm execute the data preparation code to prepare the training/validation/testing data. However, when I run the following code, it give me a error message.

```
abrahams-mbp:energyforecast abrahammathew$ python -m data_preparation.data_prep
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/Desktop/energyforecast/data_preparation/data_prep.py", line 323, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/Desktop/energyforecast/data_preparation/data_prep.py", line 318, in main
    generate_data(client, parameters)
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/Desktop/energyforecast/data_preparation/data_prep.py", line 245, in generate_data
    client)
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/Desktop/energyforecast/data_preparation/data_prep.py", line 228, in create_table
    job_config)
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/Desktop/energyforecast/data_preparation/data_prep.py", line 138, in run_query
    job_config=job_config)
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 986, in query
    job._begin(retry=retry)
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 397, in _begin
    method='POST', path=path, data=self._build_resource())
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 271, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 260, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 177, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 293, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/energy-forecasting-211800/jobs: Access Denied: Dataset energy-forecasting-211800:Energy: The user energy-forecasting@energy-forecasting-211800.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.tables.create permission for dataset energy-forecasting-211800:Energy.
```

This seems to be an issue with service accounts in GCP, so I went ahead and created 
a new service account on GCP and ran the following code.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/abrahammathew/Desktop/energyforecast/energy-forecasting-e6374529afe0.json"
```

I then reran the data perparation code by get the same error.

```
python -m data_preparation.data_prep
```

How can I get the run the code to prepare the data in the github link above? 
I'm running it though Google Cloud SDK on my mac terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Your service account "energy-forecasting@energy-forecasting-211800.iam.gserviceaccount.com" does not the permission create tables within BigQuery.

You need to create one IAM & admin -> Create Service Account. Then create a service account with the "BigQuery User" role that should sufficient as service accounts should be grant [minimum permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#granting_minimum_permissions_to_service_accounts).

Comment: This should work. Also, If you want to skip creating a new service account you can use the same one  "energy-forecasting@energy-forecasting-211800.iam.gserviceaccount.com" but adding the proper permission.